# How to replace print button with ctrl + P in desktop vb.net application

Tags: vb.net

I have desktop Application with many controls. one of the controls is a button for printing...it works fine, it prints a selected area of the form. I want to remove the print button and run the existing print code by pressing Control + p.

I should have explained that the print button and code are on a large user control with many controls on it and as you pointed out there is a problem with controls on containers on containers...Form >>TabControl >> TabPage >> User Control.

The answers were helpful but the big point was what you said.

```
Private Sub PKey_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles    MyBase.KeyDown
  If e.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.P Then
     MsgBox("This works fine...Ctrl + P were pressed")
  End If
End Sub
```

Using the code above works on a simple two or three control app but as of now when I press Ctrl + P on my many controls app, nothing happens.

Comment: _"I am aware that the code below needs to have all of the controls tabstop set to off"_ - NO! Don't do that. Just set the `KeyPreview` property of the form to True.

Comment: Also, note that `Me.Controls` doesn't include controls placed in other containers on the form like controls on a Panel or a GroupBox.

Comment: I should have explained that the print button and code are on a large user control with many controls on it and as you pointed out there is a problem with controls on containers on containers...Form >>TabControl >> TabPage >> User Control

Comment: A UserControl is not the right place to handle a hotkey. Consider doing something like `Private Sub MyForm_KeyDown(....) : If MyTabControl.SelectedTab Is MyTargetTab AndAlso e.KeyData = (Keys.Control Or Keys.P) Then ...`. And don't disable the `TabStop` property of any control _unless that's an actual requirement_ because it can frustrate the user.

Comment: Putting the KeyDown code in the Form1.vb code block with:  If e.KeyData = (Keys.Control Or Keys.P) Then MsgBox("You Pressed Ctrl + P") works fine. the problem is: writing code to trigger the subroutine code of the Print button located in the UserControl1.vb block of code.. e.g. Form1.UserControl1.btnPrint_Click(sender, e) or something similar.

Comment: Forget about the button (whether you want to keep it or not is irrelevant). Move the "print" code to a separate method with a `Public` (or `Friend`) access modifier, so in Form1, you can call it like this: `UserControl1.PrintMe()` where `PrintMe` is the name of the method. Then, if you want to keep the print button, you'd just have to call `PrintMe()` under `btnPrint_Click`.

Comment: I followed your advice changed the Public Sub Click to Public Sub myPrint() and then in the Ctrl + P code I used UserControl1.myPrint() and I get a System.NullReferenceException: 'Object variable or With block variable not set.'

Comment: I can't tell you what the problem is without seeing your current code. You could ask another question but it's almost guaranteed that it will get closed as a duplicate to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/4934172). Are you sure that `UserControl1` is the name of the UserControl on your form? My advice to you would be to learn how to debug your code. A NullReferenceException is one of the easiest exceptions to fix 99% of the time as soon as you know how to use breakpoints and step through the code. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26761773/4934172) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps that you need to do:

1. Move the code that was in your Button's Click event into its own subroutine.
2. Set the Form's [KeyPreview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?view=netframework-4.8) property to True
3. In the Form's KeyDown event use the following code:

Code:

```
Private Sub MyForm_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.P Then
        'Run print subroutine
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As it is, that will act on `Ctrl+Shift+P`, `Ctrl+Alt+P` and `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+P` as well. To act on only `Ctrl+P`, you should use `If e.KeyData = (Keys.Control Or Keys.P) Then`.

Comment: Thanks for showing the code that will respond to Ctrl + P only. I tested it and you are 100% correct.

Comment: The print code is already in its own Subroutine. The problem is it is 3 layers deep, i.e., it is code in the user control which is on a tabpage on a tabcontrol on the form. I need to be able to reference the print subroutine.  I tried Form1.TabControl1.UserControl1.btnPrint but the reference doesn't work.